# How does the TOR propagation of nodes work?

Tags: relays, onion-routing

When a relay or HSP broadcasts its key (non exit node), how does a TOR client find it?

How is the propagation of exit nodes and relay nodes (or HSPs) shared?

Answer (score 1):

All relays publish their descriptor to the directory servers.

All hidden services publish their service to the hidden service directory.

When a Tor client builds a circuit, it asks the directory server for a guard, middle, and exit relay. When you connect to a hidden service, it asks the hidden service directory for the required information to connect.